# Binary Linear Programm: Check for feasability and multiple solutions

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

Assuming, I have binary integer program, e.g. given by:

$
\arg\min_x \quad 0\\
\text{such that}\quad A_\text{eq} x = b_\text{eq}, x_i \in \{0,1\}
$

Where also $[A_\text{eq}]_{ij} \in \{0,1\} $ and $b_\text{eq} \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\} $

1. Is there any way to check whether this opt. problem is feasible?
2. Is there a way to check whether there exist multiple solutions?

Comment: This is a feasibility problem: you are asking whether there exists an x that satisfies the linear constraints $Ax=b$, right?
So the question becomes: when does a linear system have a solution and when is that unique?

Comment: yes, its only a feasibility problem but I require that the $x_i$ are binary which makes it different---to my knowledge---from solving 'normal' linear equations with real $x_i$.

Comment: indeed. I missed the integrality constraint on x. I assume that you are also looking for an efficient solution, i.e., checking the at most $2^{n}$ possible solutions (where $n$ is the dimension of $x$) is not an option, right?